# How to resolve flickering CSS in React App?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

There's a flicker when loading each page in my React app. I've tried bundling the stylesheets, but doesn't seem to get rid of the flickering.

This is my root html:

```
  <div>
    <title>{props.title}</title>
    <link href="../css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../css/webapp.webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" rel="preconnect" />
    <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="../images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="../images/webclip.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
    <link
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw=="
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css"
      rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../css/plugin.css" />
    {/*  REQUIRED CUSTOM CSS  */}
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../css/custom.css" />
    <div className="x-access-body">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]